# Swagger 2.0 Prioritization?

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0, google-api-gateway

We're currently using Swagger 2.0 as our YAML configuration.

Let's say, I have these two paths:

Path A - accepts path parameter

**GET** `https://my-gateway.com/client/{client-id}`

Path B:

**POST** `https://my-gateway.com/client/addNewClient`

As a tester, I want to verify my gateway returns correct error messages on Path B:

I want to produce - 404 Error Not Found

Test request:

**POST** `https://my-gateway.com/client/addNewClientzzz`

I'm receiving 405 instead of 404, possibly because it falls under Path A, and treats 'addNewClientzzz' as {client-id} (path parameter).

Just wondering if this is an expected behavior? Does it check first the path, and not the method?

Currently reading GCP API Gateway and OAS Documentations.

Comment: The URL with `/addNewClientzzz` does not match path B, but does match path A. The verb doesn't match and so you get the 405 Method not allowed response.. I think the answer here is yes, this is expected behaviour.